# Play JSON optional transformer

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am using Play 2.1 JSON Reads to achieve a conditional transformation.

I have a json object and I want to transform an optional field removing \n chars.The problem is that if I remove the content from the sent JSON, I obtain a validation error.

This field is optional and I don't know how to describe that the transformation is optional.
This is the current content transformation:

```
     val transformContent = (__ \ 'content).json.update(__.read[JsString].map{ 
         value =>
        JsString(value.value.replaceAll("\n", ""))
  })
```

How can I obtain an optional field transformation? Should I use the `Reads.verifyingIf`?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
val json = Json.obj("whatever" -> 1, "content" -> "hello world")
val json2 = Json.obj("whatever" -> 1)

val transformer = (__ \ 'content).json.update(
  __.readOpt[JsString].map{
    case Some(JsString(str)) => JsString(str.replaceAll("world", "scala"))
  }
).orElse(__.json.pick[JsObject])

json.transform(transformer)
//JsSuccess({"whatever":1,"content":"hello scala"},)
json2.transform(transformer)
//JsSuccess({"whatever":1},)
```

Little hacky, but it works.

Comment: `readOpt` deprecated (Since version 2.1-RC2) use `readNullable[T]` instead (which manages both missing and null fields)

Answer (score 4):

A few years later I had to change some things to make it work:

```
val json = Json.obj("whatever" -> 1, "content" -> "hello world")
val json2 = Json.obj("whatever" -> 1)

val transformer = (__ \ 'content).json.update(
  __.read[JsString].map {
    case JsString(str) => JsString(str.replaceAll("world", "scala"))
  }
).orElse(__.json.pick[JsObject])

json.transform(transformer)
//JsSuccess({"whatever":1,"content":"hello scala"},)
json2.transform(transformer)
//JsSuccess({"whatever":1},)
```

The read fails if the string is not present, thus the orElse methods handels the JsError.